# Changing same values of one collection to desire value by mongoose in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have an app in Nodejs that is using mongoose. 
I have a collection that in one field for every 15 records is saving same values but this value is a long string that I have created before.
Now I want for every 15 photos change those field values(long string) to incremental number from 1..n like :

```
'qwerasdfzxcvqwerasdfzxcv' => '1',
'qwerasdfzxcvqwerasdfzxcv' => '1',
(13 more records)...
'qazwsxedcrfvtgbyhnuhnujm' => '2',
'qazwsxedcrfvtgbyhnuhnujm' => '2',
(13 more records)...
```

JSON results from MongoDB:

```
[{"ID":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOjE5LCJpYXQiOjE1MjQwMDgzOTl9.2YvhnXtCD7-fm4B14k10m6NF7xuv7moCTbekVekkbvY","category":"Wasp","photo":"A_wasp_565","description":"","answer":"Bee","__v":0},{"ID":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOjE5LCJpYXQiOjE1MjQwMDgzOTl9.2YvhnXtCD7-fm4B14k10m6NF7xuv7moCTbekVekkbvY","category":"Wasp","photo":"A_Pompilid_wasp_007","description":"","answer":"Wasp","__v":0},{"ID":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOjE5LCJpYXQiOjE1MjQwMDgzOTl9.2YvhnXtCD7-fm4B14k10m6NF7xuv7moCTbekVekkbvY","category":"Wasp","photo":"wasp_248","description":"","answer":"Wasp","__v":0},...,{"ID":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOjE5LCJpYXQiOjE1MjQwMDgzOTl9.2YvhnXtCD7-fm4B14k10m6NF7xuv7moCTbekVekkbvY","category":"Wasp","photo":"A_wasp_555","description":"","answer":"Moth/Butterfly","__v":0},{"ID":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOjE5LCJpYXQiOjE1MjQxMTYzNzJ9.jTQ06D5nw_xuCP0q0GVzaMmi3XipeNsf_RX5tAzenh8","category":"Wasp","photo":"A_wasp_565","description":"","answer":"Wasp","__v":0},{"ID":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOjE5LCJpYXQiOjE1MjQxMTYzNzJ9.jTQ06D5nw_xuCP0q0GVzaMmi3XipeNsf_RX5tAzenh8","category":"Wasp","photo":"A_Pompilid_wasp_007","description":"","answer":"Wasp","__v":0},{"ID":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOjE5LCJpYXQiOjE1MjQxMTYzNzJ9.jTQ06D5nw_xuCP0q0GVzaMmi3XipeNsf_RX5tAzenh8","category":"Wasp","photo":"A_wasp_555","description":"","answer":"Wasp","__v":0}]}
```

I want to update above to this:

```
[{"ID":"1","category":"Wasp","photo":"A_wasp_565","description":"","answer":"Bee","__v":0},{"ID":"1","category":"Wasp","photo":"A_Pompilid_wasp_007","description":"","answer":"Wasp","__v":0},{"ID":"1","category":"Wasp","photo":"wasp_248","description":"","answer":"Wasp","__v":0},...,{"ID":"1","category":"Wasp","photo":"A_wasp_555","description":"","answer":"Moth/Butterfly","__v":0},{"ID":"2","category":"Wasp","photo":"A_wasp_565","description":"","answer":"Wasp","__v":0},{"ID":"2","category":"Wasp","photo":"A_Pompilid_wasp_007","description":"","answer":"Wasp","__v":0},{"ID":"2","category":"Wasp","photo":"A_wasp_555","description":"","answer":"Wasp","__v":0}]}
```

In this way, all those 15 records(that already has same values but long) will have the same number but readable value, not that long string.

My question is that how can I make a query to do so? (mongoose commands)

This is my model module in the node (ID is that field that I want to change):

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var SurveyAnswersSchema = new Schema({
_id: {type: String},
ID: {type: String},
answer: { type: String},
description: {type: String},
category: { type: String, enum: ['Bee', 'Beetle', 'Fly', 'Moth/Butterfly', 'Wasp' ] },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('surveyanswers', SurveyAnswersSchema);
```

What should I write here? (controller module)

```
var SurveyResults = require('../models/surveyResults');

module.exports.reportAnswers = function (callback) {

     **// instead of this line what should I write?**
      SurveyResults.find({ID: 'this.ID'},{ID: number}, callback);
};
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: Please add proper details question not quite clear.

Comment: @LalitDashora i have added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this.
This is my code. maybe useful for someone :

```
app.get('/surveyResultsUpdate', function(req, res, next){

    surveyResults.surveyResultsUpdate(function(err, answers){
        if (err)
        return next(err);

    var num =0;
    var resultsIdSet = new Set();
    answers.forEach(function(answer) {
         resultsIdSet.add(answer.Id);        
    });

    var newResults = answers; 

    var user_answer_dict = new Map();

    var counter = 0;
    for (var Id of resultsIdSet){
        num += 1;
        for ( var j in newResults) {
                if (Id === newResults[j].Id){
                    counter+=1;
                    user_answer_dict.set(counter, newResults[j]);

                    newResults[j]._id = answers[j]._id;
                    newResults[j].Id = num;
                    newResults[j].answer = answers[j].answer;
                    newResults[j].photo = answers[j].photo;
                    newResults[j].description = answers[j].description;
                    newResults[j].category = answers[j].category;
                }
            }
        }
        res.json(newResults);
    });
});
```

Results:

[image]